# «Бритти» чи «брити»?

Tags: правопис, граматика, іншомовні-слова, подвоєння

Як звучить назва британського племені за сучасним правописом? У Вікіпедії та Вікісловнику вжито форму з одним «т», а в інших словниках зустрічається з двома:

1. [slovnyk.ua](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B8)

> БРИТТИ, ів, мн. (одн. бритт, а, ч.). 1. іст. Назва кельтського народу, який колись населяв Англію.

2. [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/brytty)

> БРИ́ТТИ, ів, мн. (одн. бритт, а, чол.).
>
> 1. іст. Назва кельтського народу, який колись населяв Англію.

Comment: Slovnyk.ua має два джерела даних (згідно із зазначеним внизу сторінки): частина тлумачань із СУМ-11 (він трішки застарів), часткина тлумачень подана командою й користувачами сайту slovnyk.ua (не є найнадійнішим джерелом, бо немає конкретних відповіданьних осіб або вагомої організації, що за ним стоїть). Я більше вірю [«Словникам України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) або вже зазначеному у відповіді СУМ-20 (обидва від [УМІФ](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Український_мовно-інформаційний_фонд)).

Comment: Sasha, цілком погоджуюся з вами в тому, що в СУМ-20 новіший (а отже, правильніший) варіант, ніж у СУМ-11.

Comment: ще додатково хочу зазначити, що ви можете приймати відповіді, які вам найбільше сподобались, тоді той, хто добре відповів, отримуватиме додаткові бали й матиме більше мотивації відповідати)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Справді дуже цікаве питання. Гадаю, що потрібно використовувати варіант "брити", бо все ж таки, як зазначено в коментарях, СУМ-20 - це новіший словник.

І все ж мені стало цікаво чому є така різниця. Відповідно до [сучасного правопису](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par88):

> § 88. F, Ph, Th
>
> F і ph передаються літерою ф: фабрика, факт, фартух, фах, фаянс,
>   федеративний, фейлетон, фігура, форма, фуга, футляр, офіційний,
>   реформа; ефемерний, катастрофа, корифей, фараон, фізика, фізіологія,
>   філософія, флегматик, фонетика, фосфор; Флоренція, Франція; Філіппіни,
>   Фінікія; Лонгфелло, Фірдоусі, Фаон.
>
> Th залежно від того, як слово узвичаєне в українській мові,
>   передається то літерою ф: арифметика, ефір, кафедра, логарифм, міф,
>   орфографія, пафос, Федір, — то літерою т: бібліотека, ортодокс,
>   ортопедія, театр, теорія; Тадей, Теодор.

А ми маємо слово "Britons" або ж "Bry**th**ons" і жодних причин для того, щоб подвоїти тут приголосну "т" немає. Адже:

> 1. У загальних назвах іншомовного походження приголосні звичайно не подвоюються: акумуляція, бароко, беладона, белетристика, бравісимо,
>      ват (хоч Ватт), грип, група, групето, гун (гуни), ідилічний,
>      інтелектуальний, інтермецо, колектив, комісія, комуна, лібрето,
>      піанісимо, піцикато, стакато, сума, фін (фіни), фортисимо, шасі, шофер
>      та ін.

А також:

> 3. Подвоєні приголосні зберігаються в географічних, особових та інших власних назвах: Андорра, Гаронна, Голландія, Калькутта, Марокко,
>      Міссурі, Ніцца, Ренн, Яффа; Бетті, Джонні, Мюллер, Руссо, Фламмаріон,
>      Шиллер.
>
> **Примітка. Подвоєні приголосні зберігаються й в усіх похідних словах: андоррський (Андорра), марокканець (Марокко), яффський (Яффа).**

Тобто подвоєння було б у випадку якщо б слово оригінал було "Brittons".

Можливо такі відміності спричинені саме через різні правописи. Схожа ситуація уже обговорювалася на сайті - "[Як правильно українською “гето” чи “гетто”](http://%D0%AF%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E%20%E2%80%9C%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%E2%80%9D%20%D1%87%D0%B8%20%E2%80%9C%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%E2%80%9D?)?" Там також йшлося про відмінність між СУМ-11 і СУМ-20, причому також припускалося, що різниця спричинена різними правописами.

На жаль, слова "брит" чи "брити" немає в [Орфографічному словнику](http://padaread.com/?book=56321&pg=82). Проте, в [ЕСУМі](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_1982/EtSlUkrM_1982.pdf) на сторінці 260 пише "бритт", а також, що "брити" - це застаріий варіант.

Ще я заглянув на російську [Вікіпедію](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8B). У них слово пишеться як "бритты". Але що цікаво: там пише, що слово походить від латинського "Britto" (дві букви "т"). Я можу припустити, що так як СУМ-11 був випущений в 1970 роках, то він базувався на правописі 1960 року (метою якого було "усунути розбіжності, що вважалися небажаними при паралельному вивченні обох мов (*російської та української*)" - [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_1960_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83#cite_note-3) із посиланням на Русанівський В. М. Нове в українському правописі. — К., 1962. — с.47.) і, можливо, саме тому писалося слово "бритти" як в російській мові. Але це лише моя думка, яку важко підтвердити на 100%.

Як бачите різні офіційні джерела дають різну інформацію. Схоже на те, що спершу слово писали як "брити" (ЕСУМ), пізніше "бритти" і зараз знову "брити". Але все ж, я повторю те, що вже писав. СУМ-20 - це нове джерело, яке укладали відповідно до нового українського правопису, тому я б надав перевагу слову "брити".

Comment: Анатолію, дякую за чудово обґрунтовану відповідь!

Answer (score 4):

З [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=5545&page=207)

> [Брит](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=5545&page=207) 2, ів, мн. (одн. брит, а, ч.). 1. іст. Кельтські племена, що
>   становили основне населення Британії з VIII ст. до н. е. по V ст. н.
>   е. *Інженери не можуть зрозуміти, яким чином древні **брити**
>   спорудили Стоунхендж, не маючи під рукою ні кранів, ні потужних
>   бульдозерів (з наук.-попул. літ.).*
>
> 2. книжн., заст. Англійці. *Так ось вона – ця круча Альбіону, Вапнисто-білий невисокий щит, Який, немов удану перепону, Поперед себе
>      звів гордливий брит (М. Бажан).*

[УСЕ (Універсальний словник-енциклопедія)](http://slovopedia.org.ua/29/53393/7019.html)

> ***БРИТИ*** одне з кельтських племен, що населяли острів Великобританія; I ст. н.е. підкорені римлянами; після навали англів,
>   саксів та ютів втрималися у Валлії та на Корнуолі, а також
>   колонізували Бретань (Пн.-Зх. Галлію).

Отже, правильний варіант ***брити***

Comment: мені здається, що автор запитання бачив словники, і його цікавить обгрунтування, який з них правильний

Comment: Саме так. Зокрема, у http://sum.in.ua/s/brytty подано написання з подвоєнням.

Comment: У будь-якому разі, щиро вдячний за відповідь!

Comment: зауважте, що СУМ-20 - це новіший словник від НАН вже незалежної України, тож якщо вони оцифрували правильно - це новий стандарт (написання з одною т). Погоджуюсь, що відповідь могла б бути більш ґрунтовною.